# handling multiple files in c++

Tags: c++, header-files

I did as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995572/using-multiple-cpp-files-in-c-program#_=_) answer says but it gives an error. There are three files in my program. The `main` function, a `.h` file and a `.cpp` file. When I included the `.h` file in `main` it didn't work but when I included the `.cpp` file, declared in `.h` file, it worked fine.

`main.cpp` `//#include 'mathematica.h' didnt work but 'mathematica.cpp'`

`mathematica.h` `//declarations`

`mathematica.cpp` `//included 'mathematica.h', //Definitions`

What am I missing?

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "mathematica.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

}

//mathematica.h
#ifndef MATHEMATICA_H_INCLUDED
#define MATHEMATICA_H_INCLUDED

class time //time class start
{
    private:
        //Member variables
        int second, minute, hour;
    public:
        //Constructors
        time();
        time(int,int,int);
        //Member Functions
        void display() const;
        void add_times(const time&,const time&);
}; //time class end
#endif // MATHEMATICA_H_INCLUDED

//mathematica.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "mathematica.h"

using namespace std;

//Definition of the class 'time'
//start
//Constructor
time :: time(): hour(0), minute(0), second(0) {}

//Overloaded Constructor
time :: time(int h,int m,int s): hour(h), minute(m), second(s) {}

//display() Member Function
void time :: display() const
{
    cout<<hour<<"H:"<<minute<<"M:"<<second<<"S"<<endl;
}

//add_times() Member Function
void time :: add_times(const time& obj1,const time& obj2)
{
    hour = obj1.hour + obj2.hour;
    minute = obj1.minute + obj2.minute;
    second = obj1.second + obj2.second;
}
```

Comment: what is "didn't work" ?

Comment: by including the .h file in main doesn't compile but by including the .cpp file in main works.

Comment: ok, see my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) for `mathematica.h`

And please show your problem more clearly next time.

Comment: hey, Thanks. It compiled with out an error this time. The library wasn't licked to the project.

Comment: @Ahmad if you feel the answer is correct, just accept it.