# Can't link multiple files correctly

Tags: c++, linker, header, namespaces, linker-errors

So I am trying to get practice in with using namespaces and creating header files and linking multiple files together in visual studio. I am getting the errors: "'function int foo::doSomething(int,int)' already has a body' and "'function int goo::doSomething(int,int)' already has a body'. So I have 5 files in total. A main.cpp, foo.cpp, goo.cpp, foo.h, and goo.h. I purposefully have to function with the same parameters and name in order to get used to using namespaces. I also purposefully split them up into multiple files because I want to get comfortable linking files and user custom headers.

My main.cpp is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "goo.h"

#include "foo.h"

int main() {

    std::cout << foo::doSomething(4, 3) << '\n'; 
    return 0;


}
```

my goo.cpp is

```
:
#include <iostream>
#include "goo.h"
#include "foo.h"

int main() {

    std::cout << foo::doSomething(4, 3) << '\n'; 
    return 0;


}
```

my foo.cpp is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

namespace foo // define a namespace named foo
{
    // This doSomething() belongs to namespace foo
    int doSomething(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

my goo.h is:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "goo.cpp"

namespace goo {
int doSomething(int x, int y);
}
```

my foo.h is :

```
#pragma once
#include "foo.cpp"
#include <iostream>

namespace foo {
    int doSomething(int x, int y);

}
```

All help is truly appreciated. I have the most trouble with linking and working with multiple files and would like to just finally get it down so I do not have to troubleshoot so much in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Do not `#include` cpp files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Including .cpp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547091/including-cpp-files)

Comment: i appreciate you so much

Comment: Does it help you? [Using multiple .cpp files in c++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995572/using-multiple-cpp-files-in-c-program). As for compiling & linking, please find some tutorial on projects in the context of your favourite IDE.  Some introduction to `make` (mostly for Linux users) will also be helpful. `cmake` seems to be good further step. For absolute Linux beginners, `gcc *.cpp` is all one needs.